# Creating TextBox at runtime from a button created at runtime: defining click event

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a form where I'm adding TextBox with a [+] button, the first textbox and button is created at runtime, so, the code to define the Click event of the button is (or should be) something like:

```
AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf ButtonPlusClick
```

No problem so far, but the problem is: I need 2 parameters in *ButtonPlusClick()*: panel ID where I'm going to add textbox, as the page has an extense list of controls and sequence number of last TextBox created, in order to not repeat ID's in the page.

So here I get lost, all I've searched talks about delegates like:

```
Delegate Sub MySubDelegate(ByVal container As Panel, ByVal nseq As Integer)
Dim msd As MySubDelegate
msd = AddressOf ButtonPlusClick
msd.invoke(Panel1, 3)
```

But, hey, I'm not invoking now but defining the button1.Click event which **must call** a function that **needs parameters**, can you help me or point to some documentation?

(the final result would be a list like, and all this is created by a Class's code):

```
[TextBox] [+]
[TextBox] [+]
[TextBox] [+]
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a  `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)`. The key is the ID of the panel and the value is the count of already created `TextBoxes`.

Then you can use `FindControl(panelID`) to get the reference to your `Panel`. You need to recreate the TextBoxes from the count in `Page_Load` at the latest. Derive the ID's from the consecutive number, for example "TextBox_1", "TextBox_2"... "TextBox_10", where 10 is the `Value` in the dictionary for this panel.

In the event handler you only have to call the method which creates one textbox and sum up 1 to the dictionary value.

Comment: Mmmh, that's a beginning, testing in a stand-alone form it worked but know I have this problem: I create the controls in a Class method that is instantiated from the form which will contain the controls, so it's inside that class where I need to put _AddHandler botonMas.Click, AddressOf ButtonPlusClick_ but it's actually a button event, so, is this function defined IN the form? if yes, I can't write this line in the Class 'cos the function is not accesible, if not, where?

Comment: It looks like _ButtonPlusClick_ must be defined inside the CreateControls class and this class has a propery ContainerForm that is the form itlsef, so in _ButtonPlusClick_ I can use _ContainerForm.FindControl(ContainerPanelId)_, complex but possible!

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the same control Id in the Page_Init function back from dictionary otherwise the button_click event will not be called.